# How to infer type variables that are related from wildcard classes in Java?

Tags: java, scala, generics, groovy, type-inference

I need to call generic `f` function from a library which takes two type parameters, as demonstrated below:

```
    public <D extends Data<K> & Property<P>, K extends Key<D>, P extends Object> 
    void f(Class<D> classD, K key) {
        ...
    }
```

While `Property` is relatively simple,  `Data` and  `Key` are related:

```
    public Data<T extends Key<? extends Data<T>>> {
        ...
    }

    public Key<T extends Data<?>> {
        ...
    }
```

Now my program needs to invoke the `f` function, however, here is what I have:

```
    Class<?> clazz = ...;
    Object key = ...;
    // I know clazz and key can satisfy the constraints
    // but cannot see the exact class.

    f(clazz, key);
    // This is what I want to invoke but this statement alone
    // will lead to compile time failures.
```

I can create some local interfaces that satisfy the requirements and convert the two parameters to them, as demonstrated below.  It can pass the compiler but will lead to cast errors.

```
    public interface MyData<P> extends Property<P>, Data<MyKey<P>> {
    }

    public interface MyKey<P> extends Key<MyData<P>> {
    }
```

So my question is whether it is possible to infer the correct types `D` and `K` from wildcard in Java (or in Groovy/Scala).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to infer `Class<D>` from `Class<?>` or `K` from `Object`. The generic wildcard and Object type really mean that the compiler doesn't have any additional information about those variables' types.

Naturally, you'll get `ClassCastExceptions` when trying to cast an `Object` to a `MyKey` if it isn't one.

But if you know for a fact that `clazz` is a `Class<MyFoo>` and that `key` is a `MyBar`, given a `MyFoo` that extends `Data<MyBar>` and a `MyBar` that extends `Key<MyFoo>`, you could add some casts:

```java
f((Class<MyFoo>)clazz, (MyBar)object);
```

The compiler will warn you about type safety, but that is the cost of passing around `Class<?>`s and `Object`s.

Answer (score 0):

A `Class<?>` doesn't cover the bounded type `<D extends Data<K> & Property<P>>`, nor an `Object` can cover the bounded `K extends Key<D>`. You can specify those types in your method signature (since you can't declare them in a variable):

```
public class Types {

    public 
        <D extends Data<K> & Property<P>, K extends Key<D>, P extends Object> 
    void f(Class<D> classD, K key) {

    }

    public static 
        <D extends Data<K> & Property<P>, K extends Key<D>, P extends Object>
    void main(String[] args) {
        Types t = new Types();
        Class<D> klazz = null;
        K key = null;
        t.f(klazz, key);
    }

}

interface Data<T> {}
interface Property<T> {}
interface Key<T> {}
```

In groovy you can go dynamic and drop the types:

```
class Types {

    def f(Class<?> classD, key) {
        "foobar"
    }

    static main(args) {
        def t = new Types()
        Class<?> klazz = null
        Object key = null
        assert t.f(klazz, key) == "foobar"
    }
}


interface Data<T> {}
interface Property<T> {}
interface Key<T> {}
```